# How can I replace color shader with texture in WebGL?

Tags: html, webgl

I have to implement these options with WebGL. I'm currently getting the following error: "WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: drawArrays: attempt to access out of bounds arrays". However, my question isn't just about that. I wan't to know if I'm doing it the right way in general.

I believe the following code is the critical part I'm not doing right. **What we are trying to do is load with a color shader and only when a texture is loaded, the texture replaces the color shader.**

I'm new to this topic, please help! I'll be updating with any further details you may need.

```
function renderScene() {

  gl.viewport(pgl.viewport.x, pgl.viewport.y, pgl.viewport.width, pgl.viewport.height);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  var modelViewMatrix = mat4.create();
  mat4.multiply(modelViewMatrix, viewMatrix, modelMatrix);

  gl.useProgram(pgl.shaderProgram);

  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(pgl.shaderProgram.uModelViewMatrix, false, modelViewMatrix);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(pgl.shaderProgram.uProjMatrix, false, projMatrix);

  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(pgl.shaderProgram.aPosition);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pgl.vbo);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(pgl.shaderProgram.aPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);


  if (isColor) {
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(pgl.shaderProgram.aColor);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pgl.vboColor);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(pgl.shaderProgram.aColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  } else {
    gl.disableVertexAttribArray(pgl.shaderProgram.aColor);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(pgl.shaderProgram.aTexture);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pgl.vboTexture);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(pgl.shaderProgram.aTexture, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.uniform1i(pgl.shaderProgram.uSampler, 0);
  }
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 3);

  requestAnimationFrame(renderScene);
  updateScene();
}
```

This is the UI
[image: (IMAGE) This is the UI]

[(Pastebin.com) Here's the complete code I'm working on... sorry if it's a mess.](https://pastebin.com/2tHw8eTd)

Comment: First of all, you don't need to call`gl.uniform1i(pgl.shaderProgram.uSampler, 0);` each time. Doing it once is sufficient. But What is exactly the problem you are facing of with texture ? You have an error, this does not work ? What happen ?

Comment: We have to scale, reflect, change color and texture to the triangle. We are just not able to give it a texture. We *can* change its color but we cannot do the same with the texture.
The error we're getting is this: *"WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: drawArrays: attempt to access out of bounds arrays"* but we are not sure if the general implementation is the problem.
I'll fix the uniform1i issue, thank you.

Comment: The "out of bounds" error is related to vertex buffer, `vertexAttribPointer` etc... maybe you miscalculated something while initializing your pointers with texture coordinates... your buffer content must match (in bytes) to what you indicate using `vertexAttribPointer`. For example, if you specify a new attribute, with a bigger vertex size that include this attribute, but your buffer does not include this attrib, the pointer will reach out of bound, and you get an error. Maybe it is what happen here.